# Do not click to activate 2nd screen on Mac

Tags: macos

Is there a way to not click to activate 2nd screen on Mac?

Each time I have to do something in the 2nd screen (or viceversa) coming from the first one, I have to click the screen first then I can do what I need with the mouse. That behaviour doesn't happen on Windows or Linux, I'm tired to add that extra click each time that I have to change the screen.

For instance, to open a link in a browser, to focus some input text, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you mean window rather than screen. It's inherent in macOS, though a few controls will respond on first click, Mac is designed to not do that. Those of use used to it dislike how on Windows clicking something will action it whether you wanted it to or not.

Some controls will respond - the three dots top left of a window will respond whether that window was frontmost or not - you can see them light up as you hover over.
Some other things, like window resizing, can be actioned by holding  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  as you click - which will action without bringing the window to the front. You can select &/or open files in Finder this way too.
Window scrolling will also work on whichever window the cursor is over, whether it is frontmost or not.

For almost everything else, first click activates [brings it to the front], second click will action.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I want to throw to thrash this mac and buy a pc...

Comment: Having used Macs for 30 years, I'm the other way round. i hate that Windows does that, when in my mind, it shouldn't ever.

Comment: Have been using Linux since 1996, never had any problems like in this 2 weeks using Mac, besides the arroba, the Docks moves when I plug a 2nd screen, the other days the terminal got stucked, the audio get screwed when I plug a bluetooth, etc. I know I eventually get used to Mac but till now I can't work properly due this mismatchs on keyboard, screen, audio, etc. I opened other questions about it, with no answers